# How To Install/Root Vegan-Tab GingerEdition on Viewsonic gTablet

Tags: rooting, viewsonic-gtablet

I recently purchased a Viewsonic gTabet and want to root the device with the Vegan-Tab Ginger Edition.  I'm an absolute newbie when it comes to Android, I've been a Windows guy my whole life.

I'm looking for some instructions for "dummies" on how to get this OS installed on the tablet.  I found this site [here](http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/viewsonic-gtablet-technical/13811-rom-howto-vegan-tab-gingeredition-stable-rc1-most-popular-rom-gtablet.html), but I'm not sure if this is enough detail.  It looks like some of these steps assume prior knowledge of Android.

Does anyone have any detailed, step by step instructions on how to do this? 
Thanks for the help, looking forward to exploring this new world.

Comment: Per your second question: Gingerbread is the "codename" for Android 2.3.x, Honeycomb is (so far) Android 3.0/3.1. They are different versions of Android.

Comment: Okay, I've separated the questions, sorry about that. So is VEGAn-TAB GingerEdition, actually Gingerbread? I know you're probably saying Hellloooo, Ginger!!! Starting from scratch here, so bare with me

Comment: Not a problem, I just didn't know the answer to the first part so I didn't want to post an actual answer. But yes, it appears to be based on Android 2.3 ("Gingerbread"). The source code for 3.x has not yet been publicly released by Google, so even on tablets most custom ROMs are using 2.3 (or 2.2 sometimes).

Comment: Thanks for explaining @eldarerathis, so do you know if any other site that provides step by step instructions on how to install Ginger on the gTablet? Or is what I provided the standard? Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found this site http://viewsonic-gtablet-for-dummies.webs.com/, reading through it, its great! Just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

**Slight disclaimer**: I don't own a gTab, so I'm not particularly familiar with it. That being said, rooting devices and installing custom ROMs is at least somewhat similar across devices.

I would start by taking a look at [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1026660) over on XDA. It has links to a bunch of other threads with instructions on how to get a custom recovery (ClockworkMod) on your device, how to flash a ROM, and a bunch of other useful things. In particular, there is a pretty good [guide for installing ClockworkMod v08](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=865245), which would essentially get you to a point where you could follow the Vegan-Tab installation instructions.

Be advised that doing this will wipe all of the data on your device, so make a copy of anything you don't want to lose.